# Is there a plugin for default file location in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Is there a plugin (or a setting) in Sublime Text 2 to set the default file location for saving files?

As of now, when I open Sublime Text 2 for the first time, create a file and try to save it, the file location option defaults to:

C:\Windows\System32

I would like to set the default save file location to my Desktop so that everytime I want to save a file, the File windows opens the Desktop view. (the same idea as what can be configured e.g. in MS Word / MS Excel).

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the **Start in** field of the program's shortcut to the location you want:

[image: 1]

Comment: Once again, worked like a charm. Thanks so much, Karan!